# Bash script increments variable, but throws error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to process some files in increments of 50. It seems to work, but I'm getting an error that the command isn't found.

File sleepTest.sh:

```
#!/bash/bin

id=100

for i in {1..5}; do
    $((id+=50))

    sh argTest.sh "$id"
    sleep 2

done
```

File argTest.sh:

```
#/bash/bin

id=$1
echo "processing $id..."
```

The output is

```
sleepTest.sh: line 6: 150: command not found
processing 150
sleepTest.sh: line 6: 200: command not found
processing 200
sleepTest.sh: line 6: 250: command not found
processing 250
sleepTest.sh: line 6: 300: command not found
processing 300
sleepTest.sh: line 6: 350: command not found
processing 350
```

So it clearly has an issue with how I'm incrementing `$id`, but it is still doing it. Why? And how can I increment `$id`. I tried simply `$id+=50`, but that did not work at all.

Answer (score 4):

Leave out the `$`.

```
((id+=50))
```

`((...))` performs arithmetic. `$((...))` performs arithmetic and captures the result as a string. That would be fine if you did `echo $((...))`, but if you write just `$((...))` then the shell treats that number as the name of a command to execute.

```
var=$((21 + 21))     # var=42
echo $((21 + 21))    # echo 42
$((21 + 21))         # execute the command `42`
```

Answer (score 3):

Such assignments are legal inside arithmetic expressions. However, `bash` still tries to interpret the result of the expression as the name of a command. Either pass it as an argument to the `:` command (the POSIX way)

```
: $((id+=50))
```

or use a `bash` arithmetic *statement* instead of an arithmetic *expression*

```
((id+=50))
```